# AWS S3 pre-signed POST access denied

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im trying to generate a Signed url so that the front end can use it in uploading a photo but when i try the generated url It keeps giving me the following error

```
 <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
 <Message>Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$acl", "public-read"]</Message>
```

My back-end code to generate the pre-signed url

```
const params ={
        Bucket:'bucket-name',
        Fields:{
            key:'key-name',
            acl: 'public-read'
        },
        Expires:30*600,
        Conditions:[
            {"acl": "public-read"},
        ]
    }
    ;
    s3.createPresignedPost(params,(error,data) =>{
        console.log(error)
        res.send(data)
    })
```

And my IAM User policies

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My CORS Policy

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

**Note**: I made the s3 bucket public but the same error persists

Comment: Did your client include a POST form field of acl=public-read?

Comment: @jarmod Oh I totally missed that thanks alot now the message is access denied do u have any idea why?

Comment: The URL does not matter, what does the body contain?

Comment: Are you saying that now you've added acl=public-read, you're hitting a different error message? It's still "access denied" but it's no longer complaining about acl?

Comment: @luk2302 ``bucket,key,acl,X-Amz-Algorithm, X-Amz-Credential,X-Amz-Signature,X-Amz-Date,Policy`` These are the content of the body it I realized that I forgot acl as jarmod said but now the error is access denied

Comment: @jarmod yes exactly the response is still 403 but the error message  is now ``<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>``

Comment: You checked the URL hasn't expired yet, presumably? Did you also double-check that the (IAM user?) credentials you used to create the pre-signed URL actually have PutObject permissions on the relevant S3 bucket? I see your IAM policy but just want to be sure that you've double-checked things here.

Comment: @jarmod I doble check just now and yes it includes the putObject and I tried generating another url and made the expiration date 60 minutes but still same error

Comment: @jarmod I ended up adding all the policies to the my IAM user and it worked fine but how can i Know the required permissions

Comment: I think you're saying that it's now working if you use an IAM policy allowing `s3:*` on `arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*` but it doesn't work with just `s3:PutObject` on that same resource ARN. It may be that you also need `s3:PutObjectAcl` because you are supplying an ACL.

Comment: Is this now working?

Comment: @jarmod Im really sorry for the late reply!!. I just tried it by adding ```s3:PutObjectAcl``` it worked as a charm thanks alot.

Comment: Good to hear. I wrote up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of small problems here:

1. when you created the pre-signed URL, you indicated a condition of acl=public-read so your clients *must* include a form field of acl=public-read when POSTing their request
2. because your clients indicate an ACL, the IAM policy associated with the credentials creating the pre-signed URL must allow both s3:PutObject and s3:PutObjectAcl.